# C Isolating "only strings" in a text file

Tags: c, parsing

I have a text file, which has 1 word followed by ~100 float numbers. The float numbers are separated by space, tab, or newline. This format repeats several times throughout the text file.

For example, this is what the text file looks like:

```
one 0.00591 0.07272 -0.78274 ... 
0.0673 ...
0.0897 ...
two 0.0654 ...
0.07843 ...
0.0873 ...
three ...
...
...
```

My question is, how can I count the number of words in the file, I tried using fscanf but once it reads the first word, after that I have to skip all the floats till the next word.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you limit yourself to c?  Problems like these can be much easier solved with awk, perl, ...  Would that be an option?

Comment: Show your current code.

Comment: as @DirkHerrmann suggested, it will be easier with something else that C, unless it's some homework you have to do in C, you could also do something like using `wc` command to make the job if you just want to count words.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Ugvj6Y

Comment: @DirkHerrmann Doesn't look like a real world problem so almost certainly homework.

Comment: Yes,  I have to use C. Its for a school assignment.

Comment: the scanf family of routines is almost always the wrong choice for any serious parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it character by character (no buffer needed). I'm fairly certain the logic is sound.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_alpha(char c)
{
    //only works for some character encodings
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}
int main(void)
{
    FILE *file_ptr;
    int character;
    int prev_char_was_letter = 0;
    int word_count = 0;
    file_ptr = fopen("my_file.txt", "r");
    if (!file_ptr) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    character = fgetc(file_ptr);
    while (character != EOF)
    {
        if (is_alpha(character) && !prev_char_was_letter) 
        {
            word_count++;
            prev_char_was_letter = 1;
        }
        else if (!is_alpha(character))
        {
            prev_char_was_letter = 0;
        }
        character = fgetc(file_ptr);
    }
    printf("%d\n", word_count);
    fclose(file_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'll give you a high-level overview of a possible solution letting you figure out yourself how to translate that into C.

- Initialize a counter for the number of words (non-numbers) with zero.
- Read the file line-by-line. For each line, repeat the following:

  - Tokenize the line into white-space separated words. For each word, repeat the following:

    - If the word can be parsed into a number, do nothing and continue.
    - Otherwise, increment the counter.

Some library functions that you might find useful:

- [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to read a single line of input. It is not part of the official standard library but provided as an extension by many implementations, including GNU's libc. If you don't have it, you can roll your own using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).
- [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to tokenize a string, though it is a little awkward to use.  If you want to tokenize yourself, you'll find [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) useful. You will want to replace white-space characters with NUL bytes so you can treat the characters between them as individual NUL terminated strings.
- [`strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) to try parsing a character array into a `double`.

Instead of using a library function to parse a number into a `double`, you could also implement your own little finite automaton. This is a classical teaching example in automaton theory. See for example [this lecture](http://rosemary.umw.edu/~finlayson/class/fall14/cpsc326/notes/02-dfa1.html) (scroll down for “The Language of Floating Point Numbers”).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution to already suggested is to use strtok() for delimiting and isalpha() functions. Here is an example of a program that does the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char delim[4]={' ','\t',0x0a,0x0d};
#define MAX_LINE 1024

int isaword(char *);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    char *s;
    int wcnt=0;

    if(argc==1)
    {
        fp = stdin;
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    }
    if(fp==0)
    {
        return -1; ///file not found
    }
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        s=fgets(line,MAX_LINE,fp);
        if(s)
        {
            s=strtok(line,delim);
            while(s!=NULL)
            {
                if(isaword(s))
                {
                    wcnt++;
                }
                s=strtok(NULL,delim);    
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("word count = %d",wcnt);
    return 0;
}

int isaword(char *w)
{
    int result = 1;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(w);i++)
    {
        result = isalpha(w[i]);
        if(result==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Disclaimer in the solution - definition of "word" is based on function [isalpha](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
void foo() {
    FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char buffer[10000]; // your choice
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", buffer) > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        int word = 0;
        int number_of_dots = 0;
        while(i < strlen(buffer)) {
            if(!isdigit(buffer[i]) && buffer[i] != '.') {
                if(!(i == 0 && buffer[i] == '-')) {
                    word = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if(buffer[i] == '.') number_of_dots++;
            i++;
        }
        if(word || number_of_dots > 1) {
            printf("%s ", buffer);
            puts("It's a word!");
        }
    }
}
```